# HTML box/button to call exe on server and run it with a passed parameter MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a console application that takes one input before being able to be run. I want to be able to have a box on my razor page that takes this input and runs it through the console application. Currently this is what I have:
(so, Enter data in text field on webpage > press submit > values passes to console application and then runs)

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBox("EnterTicker")<input type="submit" value="Update" name="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Populate", "Tick")'" />
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Populate(string button)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.Arguments = button;
            psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.FileName = @"C:\---\---\---\bin\Debug\Brake3.exe";
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();           
            return View();
        }
```

On my webpage, currently, when I type in a value into the box and click the submit button, the page just says "waiting for localhost..." at the bottom infinitely. Any ideas?

Comment: You never use the value of your textbox. The only parameter in the method is `string button` which will always have the value of `"Update".

Comment: How would I make value = textbox? @StephenMuecke

Comment: The textbox has `name="EnterTicker"` so add a parameter `string EnterTicker` to the POST method and it will be populated with the value of your textbox (but of course you should be using a view model and strongly binding to that model)